# Area in terms of $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, area

> A wire of $80 \, \mathrm{cm}$ is arranged to form $3$ sides put against a wall forming a rectangle. The longest sides of the rectangle is the wall and a piece of wire with length $x \, \mathrm{cm}$.
>
> Show that area of the rectangle formed is $\dfrac{1}{2}x(80-x) \, \mathrm{cm}^2$.

I was unable to prove such however I managed to get the area as being $x^2\left(40+\dfrac{1}{2}x\right)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so you know that the perimeter of the entire thing is $2y + x = 80 \iff y = \frac{1}{2}(80-x)$, where $y$ is the length of the shorter side of the rectangle.

Now the area of the rectangle is given by $xy = x \cdot \frac{1}{2}(80-x)$.

Comment: So easy, thanks mate